# prove Hilbert's space

Tags: real-analysis

I have $C [-1,1]=\{f:[-1,1]\rightarrow R$ continuous$\}$ and an inner product (f,g)=$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x) \overline{g(x)}dx$.I want to prove C [-1,1] isn't a Hilbert's space.
I define ||f||=$sup_{-1\le x \le1} |f(x)|$ and if $x_0\in[-1,1]$the function $f \rightarrow f(x_0) $ is a linear continuous fuctional. Can I prove don't exist a function g continuous?

Comment: 1. When you have an inner product, you should use the norm that is given by the inner product, in this case 
$$\| f\|^2 = (f,f) = \int_{-1}^1 f^2 (x) dx.$$

2. The functional you gave is continuous w.r.t. the norm that you defined, but it is not continuous w.r.t the inner product norm. What would you like to say about this linear functional?

Comment: To prove that $C[-1,1]$ is not a Hilbert space, you have to show that it is not complete: find a Cauchy sequence of elements that does not converge with respect to the norm (see Xiao's comment). Remark: with respect to the supremum norm you mention the space $C[-1,1]$ is complete!

Comment: why with respect to the supremum norm the space C[−1,1] is complete?